Using Api and provider together
I am calling Get api for name and date in my profile header and also patch Api in my update profile screen now i want to use provider for upadating name immediately in my profile header now how can i use get api and provider in my profile header ??

class ProfileHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfileHeader({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final profileProvider = Provider.of<ProfileProvider>(context);

    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.green,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          const CircleAvatar(
            radius: 40,
            backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/image.png'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 16),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                profileProvider.name,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 4),
              Text(
                'Last Login: ${profileProvider.lastLogin}',
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Provider
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class ProfileProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  String _name = 'Loading...';
  String _lastLogin = 'Loading...';

  String get name => _name;
  String get lastLogin => _lastLogin;

  Future<void> fetchProfile() async {
    const String url = 'https://api.vezigo.in/v1/app/profile';
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final accessToken = prefs.getString('accessToken');

    try {
      final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
        },
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        _name = jsonResponse['data']['name'];
        _lastLogin = jsonResponse['data']['createdAt'];
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load profile');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      _name = 'Error';
      _lastLogin = 'Error';
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  Future<void> updateProfile(String newName, String newEmail) async {
    const String url = 'https://api.vezigo.in/v1/app/profile';
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final accessToken = prefs.getString('accessToken');

    try {
      final response = await http.patch(
        Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
        },
        body: json.encode({
          'name': newName,
          'email': newEmail,
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseBody = json.decode(response.body);

        _name = responseBody['data']['name'];
        notifyListeners();

        await prefs.setString('name', _name);
        await prefs.setString('email', responseBody['data']['email']);
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to update profile');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error updating profile: $error');
    }
  }
}


I tried but in my profile header in both name and date there is showing loading ..


You initialized profileProvider, but are not using it. You can use WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback to fetch profile once the widget is built.
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final profileProvider = Provider.of<ProfileProvider>(context);

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      profileProvider.fetchProfile();
    });

and use the Text widget to display:
Text(
    profileProvider.name,
    style: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
),

Additionally, I'm guessing you already added the provider to your main:
ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ProfileProvider(),


main.dart
 MultiProvider(
                  providers: [
                    ChangeNotifierProvider<DemoProvider>(
                      create: (context) => DemoProvider(),
                    ),
                    ChangeNotifierProvider<ProfileProvider>(
                      create: (context) => ProfileProvider(),
                    )
                  ],
                  child: MaterialApp(
             home: const ProfileHeader(),
                  ),
                );

wrap both text widget inside the Consumer widget,
Consumer<ProfileProvider>(
                  builder: (context, value, child) {
                    return Column(
                       children:[
                   Text(profileProvider.value.yourVariableName
                    ),
                Text('Last Login: ${profileProvider.value.lastLogin}'),
                   ]);
                  },
                ),

